# How to count a number of each distinct words repeated in a txt.file

Tags: java

I am working on a program that counts the number of t-shirts of different colours in a shop and it can't be in an `ArrayList`. For each delivery we save the colour of the t-shirt in a .txt file like this:

> red
>
> yellow
>
> red
>
> white
>
> white

So, the program will count how many red, yellow and white tshirts there are. In this case we have 2 red tshirts, 1 yellow tshirt and 2 white tshirts.

Actually, the program is about blood donations ant bloods types. But instead of colourful tshirts it's with a blood type, B blood type, O blood type and finally AB blood type. But the algorythim and code it's the same

We have already in the design a button for each type of blood and when an action is performed it shows the number of packs of that type of blood is in stock. 
We have this from user2469133

int count;

count=StringUtils.countMatches("C://sangue.txt", "O"); //where text file should be a string
                System.out.println("number of white T-shirts = "+count);

We have been searching but it appears code for arrays or hashmaps and we didin't studied the last one. we would really appreciate help

Comment: Read every value and put it in a `HashMap<string, int>`. Increase the value if it exists, otherwise add it. Write the code yourself though; as it is you're not working on your program at all.

Comment: It might be your homework....just try it yourself...or show us what have you done so far??

Comment: Does your professor know you're doing homework on SO?

Comment: The question was put on hold as a off-topic and I tried and I think the question is clear and has enough information to solve. Nevertheless thank for your effort to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download the apache common lang library and put the jar file in your class path.

then do something like this:

```
int count;
count=StringUtils.countMatches(textfile, "white"); //where text file should be a string
System.out.println("number of white T-shirts = "+count);
```

Comment: nice, thank you. We'll continue from this

Answer (score 0):

You can save them all from the text file into an ArrayList. You can then use the Collections.frequency method.

So

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("red");
list.add("red");
list.add("yellow");
list.add("blue");
list.add("red");
list.add("red");
list.add("yellow");
System.out.println("red : " + Collections.frequency(list, "red");
```

That should give you a result of 4.

Comment: *"it can't be in an ArrayList"*

Comment: Oops. Didn't see that. Have to go looking at arrays then. Won't be very scalable.

Comment: A simple `HashMap` is perfectly suited for this

Comment: It´s part of a program that can add a new blood donor and a blood donation (it's the same for tshirts and blood types), to register the list of all the donors and their information(contct donation number, sex..), to know the age and sex more frequent, how many blood types we have on stock among others. And we are having problem with this two last ones. We have been searching and it's too late to change to arrays as we did all without arrays. We never used hashmaps and it's our first year in Java, in fact our fist year with programmation. Could you please post the code? It would be very helpful